# Pipeline architecture

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, architecture, pipeline

How would one go about implementing Pipeline architecture in terms of OOP?

To better explain myself:

```
Source -> Filter -> Filter -> Filter -> Sink
```

Let's say we have a base class called PipelineStage. How would one implement Filter, Source and Sink?

I have 2 ideas :

With ISource and ISink interfaces[image: ISink interfaces]

With Sink and Source subclassing from Filter[image: subclassing from Filter]

Comment: Why does it have to be in terms of OOP? Most languages with first-class support for pipelined data flow architectures (e.g., Erlang and Go) don't use OOP to implement data flow. In fact, Erlang lacks OO facilities entirely (unless you think of a process as an object that you can send messages to) and Go only gives it a passing glance.

Comment: Well, because the application is written using OOP. The idea is to use pipelines for video processing with an ability to change pipelines in runtime etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ connect output stream to input stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410961/c-connect-output-stream-to-input-stream)

Answer (score 0):

Source and Sink seem to be excessive and complicate overall structure. They don't need to be filters.

Source is *source* and that is its function. If knows where to get data and how to pass it to the pipeline. Do not force him to be something else but source.

The same about Sink.

If you want something to validate the input - add an extra validation filter.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at chain of responsibility pattern. you can use builder pattern to build the chain based on some rules, once built, trigger the source, it processes through the chain up to end (Sink). Broken Chain problem is the common , but you can still have a way to handle it.