# Connecting two streaming functions c++

Tags: c++, stream, iostream, ostream, istream

I have two functions:

Get (std::ostream* os) and
Put (std::istream& is)

The way get functions is, it has multiple streams underneath from which it gathers the data and sends it out via the output stream os.

Put on the other hand, writes the data from input stream into multiple streams underneath which eventually stores the data.

Now, I wanted to write a piece of code to get the data using GET and do a PUT of that data.

However, I am not sure how to write to a istream or how to implement this piece of connector code. Im new to using streams and im trying to understand them too. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sethu

Comment: Check out James Kanze's old article about filtering streambufs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you want to create something that channels the data written to `Get()`'s `std::ostream` to `Put()`'s `std::istream`. To do so you'll need to write a suitable stream which may need to deal with connecting multiple threads. If it is sufficient to read data from the stream written to by `Get()` after returning from `Get()`, you can just write to an `std::ostringstream` and make the written bytes available to `Put()` using an `std::istringstream`. I'm assuming you want a more direct connection and describe the general approach.

The underlying mechanics of streams are implement in stream buffers, i.e., classes derived from `std::streambuf` (or, if you want to support other character types like `wchar_t` or `char32_t`, the class template `std::basic_streambuf`. The key functions to override are

- `overflow(int_type)` which is called for an output stream whenever the stream buffer's buffer is full.
- `sync()` which is called for output streams when the stream's buffer needs to be flushed.
- `underflow()` which is called for input stream if the stream's buffer is drained.

The details of how to implement the processing are a tad bit more involved. I have written many answers explaining various uses creating stream buffers. For a stream connecting an output stream to an input stream have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12413298/1120273).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer before writing the comment about James' article. But it's probably useful with multiple discussions of the same issue. :) As it happened I consulted that article just a few days ago to deal with a bug in g++'s iostreams, where it generated double newlines on input when the streams were set to direct i/o mode in Windows (that's for console input). The solution I adopted was to call `pubsync()` on the original buffer after every newline received. Strange. ;-)